# Tcl regexp does not escape asterisk (*)

Tags: regex, escaping, tcl

In my script I get a string that looks like this:

```
Reading thisfile.txt
"lib" maps to directory somedir/work.
"superlib" maps to directory somedir/work.
"anotherlib" maps to directory somedir/anotherlib.
** Error: (errorcode) Cannot access file "somedir/anotherlib". <--
No such file or directory. (errno = ENOENT)                    <--  
Reading anotherfile.txt
.....
```

But the two marked lines with the error code only appear from time to time.
I'm trying to use a regexpression to get the lines from after `Reading thisfile.txt` to the line before either `Reading anotherfile.txt` or, if it is there, before `**`.

So `result` should in every case look like this:

```
"lib" maps to directory somedir/work.
"superlib" maps to directory somedir/work.
"anotherlib" maps to directory somedir/anotherlib.
```

I have tried it with this regexp:

```
set pattern ".*Reading thisfile.txt\n(.*)\n.*Reading .*$"
```

Then I do

```
regexp -all $pattern $data -> result
```

But that only works if there is no error message.
So I'm trying to look for the *.

```
set pattern ".*Reading thisfile.txt\n(.*)\n.*\[\*|Reading\].*$"
```

But that also does not work. The part with `** Error` is still there.

I wonder why. This one doesn't even compile:

```
set pattern ".*Reading thisfile.txt\n(.*)\n.*\*?.*Reading .*$"
```

any idea how I can find the and not match the *?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the way you wrote your regex, you will have to use braces:

```
set pattern {.*Reading thisfile\.txt\n(.*)\n.*\*?.*Reading .*$}
```

If you used quotes, you would have had to use:

```
set pattern ".*Reading thisfile\\.txt\n(.*)\n.*\\*?.*Reading .*$"
```

i.e. basically put a second backslash to escape the first ones.

The above will be able to grab something; albeit everything between the first and the last `Reading`.

If you want to match from `Reading thisfile.txt` to the next line beginning with asterisk, then you could use:

```
set pattern {^Reading thisfile\.txt\n(.*?)\n(?=^Reading|^\*)}
regexp -all -lineanchor -- $pattern $data -> result
```

`(?=^Reading|^\*)` is a positive lookahead and I changed your `(.*)` to `(.*?)` so that you really get all the occurrences and not from the first to the last `Reading`.

The positive lookahead will match if either `Reading` or `*` is ahead and are both starting on a new line.

[`-lineanchor`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/regexp.htm#M10) makes `^` match at every beginning of line instead of at the start of the string.

[codepad demo](http://codepad.org/udBssvnb)

---

I forgot to mention that if you have more than one match, you will have to `set` the results of the regexp and use the `-inline` modifier instead of using the above construct (else you'll get only the last submatch)...

```
set results [regexp -all -inline -lineanchor -- $pattern $data]
foreach {main sub} $results {
  puts $sub
}
```

Comment: Use `set` or directly put the regexp in the loop as the list.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unfamiliar with tcl but the following regex will give you matches of which the 1st capture-group contains the filename and the 2nd capture-group contains all the lines you want:

```
^Reading ([^\n]*)\n((?:[^\n]|\n(?!Reading|\*\*))*)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/FuLJmsuW5ssJ6x-F)

Basically the `(?:[^\n]|\n(?!Reading|\*\*))*` is saying *"Match anything that isn't a new-line character or a new-line character not followed by either `Reading` or `**`"*.

What I'm getting from Jerry's answer is you'd define that in tcl like so:

```
set pattern {^Reading ([^\n]*)\n((?:[^\n]|\n(?!Reading|\*\*))*)}
```

Comment: the idea is nice but it doesn't work properly for me.